# Changing the particle image of a particle effect in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make it so when a particle hits a certain block(dirt, grass, rock) it does a little mini explosion of that type of blocks Texture. I don't want to make a ton of particles for the hundreds of block types I have so is there a way to do this at runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can libgdx Particle Effects use texture regions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531814/can-libgdx-particle-effects-use-texture-regions)

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Is this why you were asking about the `ParticleEmitter` class?

You should be able to do this by creating a Sprite with the texture you want, and then call the ParticleEmitter's `setSprite(Sprite sprite)` method.

Caveat - I haven't actually done this myself, but it ought to work.